# Multiple websites on same IP with different ports withIIS

Tags: iis, ports

I had some test sites setup on a server that had one IP and utilized different ports for the site like this.

www.acme.com:5000
www.acme.com:6000

This worked great until a SSL certificate was installed on the server. Now the sites above are not coming up.

How do I configure them so that they come up again?

Comment: I added another Port for the SSL so I now have two. 443 and 6000. I went to the new site and assigned it 5900 and 6000 for the SSL. I went to https://site.com:6000 and nothing comes up.

Comment: @chopps - Have you confirmed the site works over 443? Have you ensured that the SSL cert was assigned to the binding on port 6000? I'm assuming there are no local firewalls blocking traffic over port 6000?

Comment: @chopps - Btw, one problem I see is that the browsers are not happy communicating via SSL over a port other than 443. Technically, it's possible but they all have (IE, FF, Chrome) mechanisms to protect the user and balk at SSL traffic over something other than 443.

Comment: @chopps - Still, it should work in IE assuming there aren't any firewalls in the way.

Comment: you know...i bet you the firewall thats in place is preventing the site from coming up. The site not using SSL of:5900 should come up but its not. The firewall is forcing all requests to be SSL.

Comment: @chopps - It won't be that the firewall is forcing all requests to be SSL. It will be that the firewall between you and the web server only has ports 80 and 443 open.

Comment: @chopps - Most firewalls will not be able to determine if the traffic is SSL or not. Rather, they will simply assume that traffic on a 443 is SSL. Can you access your site via http on port 6000?

Comment: I can't access via port 6000(ssl) or 5900

Comment: @chopps - Can you access your site over http (not https) and port 6000? I.e., I'm trying to determine whether that port is actually blocked or not. If you can access your site over port 6000 via normal http, then the port is open otherwise it is likely blocked. Also note, that it is possible to enable the firewall on the server itself as different from your network firewall. This would be something else to check.

Comment: I tried all the sites I configured using various ports and none of them work. i.e. (3000, 4000, 5000 and this one). They all worked until the SSL cert as installed and no matter what I do to the configuration none of them come up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SSL can only segmented by IP and Port. You can however can run SSL over a different port than 443 by simply adding a binding for https and a different port.

In IIS 7.x, in the Bindings for the site, you would add one for SSL and change the port:

[image]

What would also need to happen, which isn't shown in this image is the selection of the appropriate SSL certificate which would need to be configured on the server. With that set, you would then access the site by going to:

`https://mysite:1234/...`