# Will the browsers show the "Connection untrusted" error for non 443 port

Tags: ssl, iis, browser, https, certificate

I want to buy and apply the certificate for website https://domain.com:8097 (https with non default port 443). Will the browsers show any errors in this case (for example, red notification about untrusted connection in Chrome)?

I'm asking because of this comment in thread - [Multiple websites on same IP with different ports withIIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734150/multiple-websites-on-same-ip-with-different-ports-withiis#comment6560236_5734150)

> "@chopps - Btw, one problem I see is that the browsers are not happy
>   communicating via SSL over a port other than 443. Technically, it's
>   possible but they all have (IE, FF, Chrome) mechanisms to protect the
>   user and balk at SSL traffic over something other than 443."

443 port is busy so I can't use it. Please don't suggest me to buy new domain name. I know that certificate is applied for domain name, not the port, but I just want to make sure that the browsers will work fine in such situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The red warning that the browser displays may be due to many reasons, **but not because the port is not 443**:

- certificate hostname and web domain does not match
- certificate root CA is not in browser truststore
- server is not providing the certification chain
- certificate expired
- ...

The default port for https is 443, but you can use any free port. What you have to keep in mind is that by not using a standard port you may have problems with the client's firewall. For example it is common that in corporate networks only a small set of ports is open (e.g., 80 and 443), and client connections to non-standard ports will be rejected

Note: About the comment you have linked, the author is also considering whether the OP has a firewall, and finally he has posted an answer that contains

> You can however can run SSL over a different port than 443 by simply adding a binding for https and a different port